# Windows Authentication not getting enabled in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I am just starting to learn ASP.NET. I opened a default ASP.NET application and changed the web.config file to enable Windows authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>
```

When I run from VS using the asp.net development server, it is able to detect my windows login and display it.
I tried publishing it to the IIS server 7.5 in the same PC and ran from there. Now my windows login is not getting detected.
I have enabled the Windows Authentication from the Authentication feature in IIS. 
What else I might be missing in this case?

Thanks..

Comment: You need to set up your site in IIS to use Windows Auth: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try disabling Anonymous Authentication in IIS 7.5 for that web-site.

- Open IIS Console.
- Select website.
- Double-click "Authentication"
- Ensure "Anonymous Authentication" is disabled

Only "Windows Authentication" should be enabled for your purposes.

The reason this works is that a browser will perform the first request anonymously. If anonymous authentication is enabled this request will succeed, and so the web-server will have no idea who you are.

If you use a tool like Fiddler to examine the network traffic between you and the server, you will notice that you actually get 3 requests if Windows Authentication is the only configured method. The requests get the following responses:

- Request 1: "Please can I log-in anonymously?"
- *Response 1: "NO!!!" [HTTP Status Code 401]*
- Request 2: "Alright, what **do** you support?"
- *Response 2: "I support Windows Authentication" [HTTP Status Code 401]*
- Request 3: "Alright - here's my Windows token"
- *Response 3: "Hi RB, here's your web-page" [HTTP Status Code 200]*

Comment: @Manoj - I've updated my answer with the reason why it made a difference.

Comment: Was able to see the relevant packets in fiddler! Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: @RB. When I open authentication in IIS getting an error with status retrieving... any idea how to resolve.